# How to create a generic rule in vee-validate v3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vee-validate

Its possible to create a generic validation rule to use in multiple elements?

```
genericRule: {

required:'required',

min:'min',

etc..

}
```

On the form

```
<ValidationProvider
  name="genericRule"
  rules="required|min|etc"
>
<input v-model='a'/>
</ValidationProvider>
<ValidationProvider
  name="genericRule"
  rules="required|min|etc"
>
<input v-model='b'/>
</ValidationProvider>
```

**In version 3, if i repeat the same rule in multiple objects i got BAD validation.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can reference a set of validation rules defined in your component in multiple `ValidationProvider`s. You have to use the `rules` prop on the  `ValidationProvider` rather than the `name` prop.

For example:

In the template:

```html
<ValidationProvider
  name="fieldA"
  :rules="genericRule"
>
    <input v-model='a'/>
</ValidationProvider>

<ValidationProvider
  name="fieldB"
  :rules="genericRule"
>
    <input v-model='b'/>
</ValidationProvider>
```

In the component:

```js
data() {
    return {
        genericRule: {
            required: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a possibility to use the genericRule from my custom vee validations file?. I think repeating code rules in every component its not ideal

Comment: whats the meaning of name in provider if we are not using the validation file rules?

Comment: Yes, you could import the rule from another file and add it to your data function. A mixin would also work. Basically any way that allows you to reference the object in the template.

Comment: The name prop is the name of the field, not the name of the rule. It’s used in error messages.